# How to Pivot a Pandas dataframe into a new format with mixed data type and possible doublicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logging, pivot

I am working with a large dataset. I extract all the data from the dataset in a table that look like this (Out Put 1):

```
Label                                                 Value

Time
2010-01-01 00:00:30.560    AAAAA                     [3] 
2010-01-01 00:00:30.560    BB                    -2.6000 
2010-01-01 00:00:30.560    C                      -2.2000 
2010-01-01 00:00:30.560    DD                      0.0000 
2010-01-01 00:00:40.160    GG                      1_2_3
```

my goal is to change this to and take out and dummy variable Label and value and make the time as my index

```
  Time                      AAAA   BB     C   DD   GG
2010-01-01 00:00:30.560      3    -2.6  -2.2   0   NaN
2010-01-01 00:00:40.160     NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN 1_2_3
```

My code look like this :

```
logparser = parse_filter_logfile('CleanLog2.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(logparser, columns = ['Time', 'Label', 'Value'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S.%f") #I get Output 1 here

H=df.set_index(['Time', 'Label']).unstack(-1)  #error I get the error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

I tried several things but didn't have any luck with this.
When I use this  I get this error

```
df.pivot(index='Time', columns='Code') #Error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

When I used this I get this error:

```
df.pivot(index='Time', columns='Code',aggfunc='mean') #pivot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aggfunc'
```

I appreciate if anyone can help. 
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I used

```
 H=df.pivot_table(index='Time', columns='Code', values='Value',aggfunc='first')
```

and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use pivot_table not pivot.
It's hard to tell without example data but this should work

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values="Value",index='Time', columns='Code',aggfunc='mean')
```

If you have non numeric data, you should handle that separately then combine it with the numeric data.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I changed to pivot_table and used aggfunc='first' and that solved the problem.